# Qt Custom Widget Plugin Q_Property With Enum

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

In my custom designer widget plugin I have a custom widget that derives QProgressBar. I have a field to chose either a determinate or indeterminate state. For this I have simply made an enum with the two states. I would like to use these values in the QtDesigner widget property area via implementing a Q_PROPERTY macro as follows:

```
class QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT QtMaterialProgress : public QProgressBar
{   
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor progressColor WRITE setProgressColor READ progressColor)
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor backgroundColor WRITE setProgressColor READ backgroundColor)
    Q_PROPERTY(Material::ProgressType progressType WRITE setProgressType READ progressType)
.....
```

And also here is the enum declaration:

```
enum ProgressType
{
    DeterminateProgress,
    IndeterminateProgress
};
```

I would expect this piece of code to produce a QComboBox in the property editor of QtDesigner with the two states, however I get non of the such. I have also tried adding `Q_ENUMS(PropertyType)` to the header with no luck.

Comment: Do not use Q_ENUMS, use Q_ENUM, it works for me: https://imgur.com/a/C17lX

Comment: Add add `Q_ENUM(Material::ProgressType)` to my header and still nothing, I had to change the parent of the enum to be a public class inheriting `QObject` and I still get no list in the disigner. Where did you place the `Q_ENUM()`

Comment: This is my test: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49172604, If you share a code that can be reproduced, it would help more people, but with that mystery attitude there will not be much help, I recommend you provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc that worked correctly, if you post it I'll accept it and the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Q_ENUM` (Not `Q_ENUMS` since it is deprecated from Qt 5.5: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew55.html) as the following example shows:

```
#ifndef TESTWIDGET_H
#define TESTWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class TestWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(EnumTest test READ test WRITE setTest)
public:
    TestWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    enum EnumTest { ENUM0, ENUM1, ENUM2, ENUM3 };
    Q_ENUM(EnumTest)

    EnumTest test() const;
    void setTest(const EnumTest &test);

private:
    EnumTest mTest;
};

#endif
```

[image]

<sub>In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/49172604) you can find a complete example</sub>